# Distinguish JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, events, dom, compare, comparison

What is the best way to distinguish events in JavaScript.

Actually there are two points I am interested in. The first one is are there something like id in event (it would be very useful foe debugging purposes). And another point are there better ways to distinguish `mousedown` and `mousedown`&`touchstart` events.

Let me tell you my story. I met the problem that if you add two dom events to a node with triggers `mousedown` and `touchstart`, then on mobile devices both `mousedown` and `touchstart` run.

The first solution I found was to run

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

at the beginning of each listener function.

But then I found out an event delegation pattern and started to work with analytics, all that disallowed to use the previous approach, so I come up with the following solution:

```
let lastEvent = null;
const specificListener = function(e) {
  if (lastEvent === e) {
    return; //already run the code due to another listener
  }

  /*
  logic goes here
  */ 

  lastEvent = e;
};
```

And now I am interested whether or not it is possible to compare events in a different way (different from event1 === event2, hope to find out about something like event1.id === event2.id)?

Thank you.

Comment: _on mobile devices both `mousedown` and `touchstart` run_.....strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to differentiate the events, just subscribe to `mousedown` only, as it is fired anyway. That's the most simple solution I'd say.

Or, you could try to detect which event system is supported and only subscribe to the appropriate one:

```
var eventType = document.ontouchstart != null ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';

document.addEventListener(eventType, (e) => { ... });
```

A third solution (possibly) would be to use `PointerEvents` only, but that depends on the platforms you need to support.
https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer%20events

If you for sure cannot use one of these approaches: Every event should have a timestamp property (not sure if it is named that way), maybe you can find a way to distinguish two events with it.